# Linear independent eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> I have T as a linear transformation from V to V over the field F, V has dimension n. T has the maximum number n distinct eigenvalues, then show that there exists a basis of V consisting of eigenvectors.

I know that if I let $v_1,...,v_r$ be eigenvectors belonging to distinct eigenvalues, then those vectors are linearly independent. Can I make a basis from these linearly independent vector and prove that it spans V?

Also, what will the matrix of T be in respect to this basis?

Thank you for any input!

Comment: If there are $n$ linearly independent vectors in  $n$-dimensional space, then they **must** form a basis. To see what $T$ looks like, consider what $T x_k$ looks like in the basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @Akaichan Do you still need help with this or is Copper.Hat's comment enough.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a *basis* for $V$ is a linearly-independent set of vectors in $V$ that spans the space $V,$ and the *dimension* of a finite-dimensional vector space is the number of elements in a basis for $V,$ so we know that any basis for $V$ must contain exactly $n$ linearly-independent vectors.  We also know (see Theorem 5 on page 45 of Hoffman and Kunze's *[Linear Algebra](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit)*) that every linearly-independent subset of $V$ is part of a basis for $V.$  You already know that the $n$ eigenvectors are linearly independent, so it follows that they form a basis for $V.$

To find the matrix of $T$ with respect your ordered basis $\mathscr B$ of eigenvectors, we use the fact that the *i*th column of that matrix is given by $[Tv_i]_{\mathscr B}$ where $[ \cdot ]_{\mathscr B}$ denotes the coordinate matrix with respect to $\mathscr B.$  We therefore compute
$$[Tv_i]_{\mathscr B}  = [\lambda_i v_i]_{\mathscr B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ \vdots\\ 0\\ \lambda_i\\ 0\\ \vdots\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue associated with eigenvector $v_i.$  Thus, the matrix of $T$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues in the diagonal entries ordered by corresponding eigenvectors:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0         & \cdots & 0\\
0         & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots\\
0         & 0         & \cdots & \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}.$$